# Start service with Secret Code android

Tags: android

I want to start my service application from entering secret code call diler and it dosnt work.

Here is my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org..."
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".IncomingCall" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="sniffingService"
            android:label="androidCallProvider" >
        </service>

        <receiver android:name=".secretCodeApplicationStarter$onReceive" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="android_secret_code" 
                    android:host="9091"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my Broadcast Receiver :

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class secretCodeApplicationStarter extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE")) {
            Log.d("Helloo","Helloo");
            Intent i= new Intent(context, sniffingService.class);
            context.startService(i); 
        }
    }

}
```

This is never execute so my service never starts too. Any ideas ?

Comment: Is android:scheme="android_secret_code" the variable that contains the expected secret code? Like this it is expecting "android_secret_code", if you're actually searching for the string named "android_secret_code" change it to android:scheme="@string/android_secret_code".

Comment: You want to add in the string resurces android_secret_code = 9091 ?

Comment: Find a secret code that already works to launch something else. For example, on the Galaxy S4, *#06# launches a thing that shows you your MEID. Once you have found a code that works, try setting YOUR code to that same code and see if it launches.

This is where I am now in trying to figure out this problem. If I set an arbitrary code, nothing happens on the S4. If I hijack an existing code (like 06), it works. The implication is that somewhere there is a list of codes for which the dialer will launch a broadcast. Where is this list? Can it be added to? That is the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:name=".secretCodeApplicationStarter"` instead of `android:name=".secretCodeApplicationStarter$onReceive"` in your receiver declaration.

Comment: Your app must have been launched in order to make the Receiver active. Fix your Manifest's entry for your MainActivity so that it can be launched via a normal launcher and launch it. Then try again dialing the secret code.

Comment: I want to make my application invisible with no icons etc I was wondering if I can achive it with this codes or I should look for smethin else as decision ?

Comment: Your might want to open a new question on how to make your app invisible. Regarding your original problem here: See my previous two comments on what you have to do.

Comment: What phone or Android version? I'm having a similar problem. Secret code works great on older phones with older Android but when I try the exact same thing on a Galaxy S4, the dialer does not seem to make the broadcast.